# Text overflow in h2 with border

Tags: html, css

I want an h2 element, with a double border. Currently I have this snippet, HTML+CSS:

```css
h2.titulo {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #8c2638;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
}

h2.titulo span {
  padding: 11px 0;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8c2638;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="titulo"><span>My title</span></h2>
```

I would like this title to be responsive, when I have a very long title, I think the best way is **text-overflow: ellipsis** with **overflow:hidden**. I tried this, but overflow hidden on h2 makes red border bottom dissapear:

```css
h2.titulo {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #8c2638;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h2.titulo span {
  padding: 11px 0;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8c2638;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="titulo"><span>A very very very very very very very very long long title</span></h2>
```

The closest approach is this, but red border is not exactly collapsed with the other border:

```css
h2.titulo {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #8c2638;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

h2.titulo span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8c2638;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="titulo"><span>Normal title</span></h2>
```

And  margin-bottom:-1px; on span does not do the trick because of overflow. Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to your span and remove bottom-padding from `h2`.

Also your `margin-bottom:-1px` is not working because `span` is an `inline` element by default, which provides no visual change by itself like `padding` or `margin`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
h2.titulo {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 0 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #8c2638;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h2.titulo span {
  padding: 11px 0;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8c2638;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="titulo"><span>A very very very very very very very very long long title</span></h2>

<h2 class="titulo"><span>NORMAL TITLE</span></h2>
```

**Updated:** if you want border to be collapsed use `box-shadow` instead of `border`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
h2.titulo {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 0 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #8c2638;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px 0px #ccc inset;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h2.titulo span {
  padding: 11px 0;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px 0px #8c2638 inset;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="titulo"><span>A very very very very very very very very long long title</span></h2>

<h2 class="titulo"><span>NORMAL TITLE</span></h2>
```

Comment: But borders are not exactly collapsed. Red border is on top of grey border.

Comment: @jfmarquez If you want to border to be collapsed use `box-shadow` instead of `border`....Updated..!

Answer (score 0):

Putting the div inside a pair of divs could do the trick as divs are height auto and full width as default, but you can set the second one to display it as inline-block, then it will apply the border correctly.

```css
div.titleBox{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div.border{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8c2638;
  display: inline-block;
}
h2.titulo {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #8c2638;
    font-size: 25px;
}

h2.titulo span {
    padding: 11px 0;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-size: 25px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="titleBox"><div class="border"><h2 class="titulo"><span>This is a short title</span></h2></div></div>


<div class="titleBox"><div class="border"><h2 class="titulo"><span>This is a very very very very very vbery very large one!</span></h2></div></div>
```

Doing it with an H2 which is a block by default could cause you headaches.

```css
h2.titulo {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #8c2638;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

h2.titulo span {
    padding: 11px 0;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-size: 25px;
    word-break: break-all;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8c2638;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="titulo"><span>This is a short title</span></h2>


<h2 class="titulo"><span>This is a very very very very very vbery very large one!</span></h2>
```

But you can solve it deleting h2 padding and displaying the span as inline-block

Comment: But borders are not exactly collapsed. Red border is on top of grey border.

Comment: Edited with a simply margin: -1px; Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks JoelBonetR, but I would like (if it is possible), text-overflow: ellipsis,  word-break is not supported in Edge.

Comment: it's supported since 5.5 version: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

cheers!

Comment: I was wrong, it is not fully supported but yes basic support. Thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

What about using ::after or ::before to add an exstra border?

I suppose it is an extra border for the "h2" element